# fixing let variable declaration in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, browser

I am having a script, a big one, it has about five loops, I was testing it in Firefox, Chrome, Edge, it was fine, but IE is there always for us to cause problem, I knew that there is problems with IE always when it comes to CSS, but I was not taking it in consideration in my work in general, but now I am working on a project that has to take IE on consideration.

IE does not support let declaration in loops, and it deals with them as they are var variable which causes problem ofc, I understand that, but I have to modify my code so it can work because it will take a lot of time to redo all of it, so I tried a solution found somewhere here in stack, I was adding a line inside the loop, where I affect my counter to a new variable and use that variable like that ( first line in loop ) :

```
// render elements
renderData(data);


// methods

function renderData(newData) {
    cdiscountHeaderOptionsContainer.innerHTML = "";

    for (let counter = 0; counter < newData.length; counter++) {
        let j = counter;
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        let aTextNode = document.createTextNode(newData[counter].label);
        a.appendChild(aTextNode);
        a.href = "#";
        a.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                if (newData[j].options.length !== 0) showDetails(newData[j].id - 1);
                else window.open("https://www.cdiscount.com/voyages/v-145-0.html");
            } else {
                window.open("https://www.cdiscount.com/voyages/v-145-0.html");
            }
        })
        a.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            if (!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
                showDetails(newData[j].id - 1);
            }

        })
        cdiscountHeaderOptionsContainer.appendChild(a);
    }
}
```

Instead of this :

```
// render elements
renderData(data);


// methods

function renderData(newData) {
    cdiscountHeaderOptionsContainer.innerHTML = "";

    for (let counter = 0; counter < newData.length; counter++) {

        let a = document.createElement("a");
        let aTextNode = document.createTextNode(newData[counter].label);
        a.appendChild(aTextNode);
        a.href = "#";
        a.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                if (newData[counter].options.length !== 0) showDetails(newData[counter].id - 1);
                else window.open("https://www.cdiscount.com/voyages/v-145-0.html");
            } else {
                window.open("https://www.cdiscount.com/voyages/v-145-0.html");
            }
        })
        a.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            if (!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
                showDetails(newData[counter].id - 1);
            }

        })
        cdiscountHeaderOptionsContainer.appendChild(a);
    }
}
```

But now working too, why ? I dont know, and that's why I am here :).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use Babel instead, to transpile to ES5 automatically? Don't do it manually

Comment: I did not get what you are saying

Comment: Once you have ES2015+ code that works, just plug it into Babel and get the transpiled ES5 result, and its syntax will work in IE.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by the community members about using the Babel.js to transpile your es6 code to es5 code. It can help to fix this issue.

Comment: I already did, but having a problem, maybe it is not the problem, my elements ( dynamically added ) are not displayed in IE11

Comment: Do you mean you met with another issue after successfully adding the Babel? What error did you get? Please try to provide detailed information about it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance my code was fine, the answer is not what you refered to

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Well, I have downloaded IE11 and for some reason I found js is disabled there, imagine :), stupid IE11

Comment: Does your code work properly after you enabled the JavaScript in the IE browser? If yes, then thanks for updating us with the answer to this question. Let us know if you have further questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT The question has been closed By Mr.CertainPerformance, I can't provide an answe now, even though the answer he proposed in not valid, the power of stackoverflow, letting people who think they know decide